# Get Lists from site within specific date range

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, caml-query

I am applying modified date time filter on SPlist. For that I need to iterate list collection and check its date. Is there any query which can be execute the get filtered SPlist collection?

Answer (score 0):

[Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms426449.aspx) is an XML-based language that is used in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation to define the fields and views that are used in sites and lists.

You cannot use CAML Query to query list collection.

You can get the last modified date of the list by [List.LastItemModifiedDate property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) in [List class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.aspx). Iterate the lists and check LastItemModifiedDate property of each list.